# C++ мин. и макс. элемент массива за один проход

Tags: c++, массивы

нужно массив из 12 чисел заполнить с клавиатуры и за один проход найти максимальный и минимальный элемент в нем. написал код но не понимаю почему не работает. подскажите пожалуйста

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int arr[12], min, max;
    for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
        cin >> arr[i];
    }
    do {
        min = arr[0];
        max = arr[0];
    } while (0);
    for (int k = 1; k < 12; k++) {
        if (arr[k] > max) {
            max = arr[k];
        }
        else if (arr[k] < min) {
            min = arr[k];
        }
    cout << "max is: " << max << " " << "min is: " << min;
    return 0;
        }
}
```

Comment: Что вы хотели спрашивать? Где вопрос?

Comment: Уберите цикл `do - while`

Comment: вы хоть сами знаете что это такое? `do { min = arr[0]; max = arr[0]; } while (0);`

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/minmax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a, min, max;
    cin >> a;
    min = max = a;
    for (int i = 1; i < 12; i++) {
        cin >> a;
        if (min > a) min = a; 
        if (max < a) max = a; 
    }
    cout << "max is: " << max << " " << "min is: " << min;
}
```

Если ну никак без массива -

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a[12], min, max;
    cin >> a[0];
    min = max = a[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < 12; i++) {
        cin >> a[i];
        if (min > a[i]) min = a[i]; 
        if (max < a[i]) max = a[i]; 
    }
    cout << "max is: " << max << " " << "min is: " << min;
}
```

**Update**

Кстати, у вас для исправления ситуации было достаточно заменить

```
cout << "max is: " << max << " " << "min is: " << min;
return 0;
    }
```

на

```
    }
cout << "max is: " << max << " " << "min is: " << min;
return 0;
```

Все после этого работает :)

Comment: Гляньте еще на **Update** в ответе...

Comment: понял. а еще вопросик, подскажите, правильно ли я понимаю do .... while(0) : это значит что этот цикл выполнится ровно 1 раз. так ли это ?

Comment: Да, именно так - одно выполнение. Так что особого смысла не имеет, можно просто написать тело цикла без "обертки".

Answer (score 1):

У вас так же не присвоено значение max и min. В некоторых случаях может найти неправильный максимум или минимум. Нужно для максимального элемента устанавливать то значение, которого не может быть. Например для массива из положительных чисел. max должен быть равен -1 к примеру. А min должен быть равен числу которое будет всегда больше любого. Например макс. число массива 1000. min должен быть 1001.

Comment: да, я думал об этом, но подумал что это как то не честно. а вдруг в масиве будет огромное число ?

Comment: нет автор присваивает переменным `min` и `max` значения из массива и поэтому на код это не влияет

Comment: можно объявить переменные min и max с другим типом данных, например long, им присвоить им значения из limits.h LONG_MIN/LONG_MAX, в этом случае они будут явно за диапазоном значений int, и алгоритм отработает правильно. хотя если присвоить им в начале цикла обоим значение первого элемента, то тоже правильно отработает.